# How to search and count multiple names in a range

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I am having some problems using the COUNTIF or COUNTIFS functions in google sheets. I have a range of the names of all students "Students!A1:FL30". I want to count how many have the names `A3="Mike" B3="Mark" and C3="Matt"`. If I try to count the amount of times one of these names pop up with `COUNTIFS(Students!A1:FL30,A3)`. Then it works fine. However if I am trying to count for more than just 1 name it returns 0 instead.

I guess it is possible to do `COUNTIFS(Students!A1:FL30,A3) + COUNTIFS(Students!A1:FL30,B3) + COUNTIFS(Students!A1:FL30,C3)` but it feels very repetitive and looks as if I am using countifs wrong.

Does anyone know how to streamline this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS` with an array conditions as follows:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(Students!A1:FL30,{A3, B3, C3})))`

Here you can see an example in Google Sheets:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. For some reason it is only returning the value of the first cell in the array. A3 yields 19 counts, B3 16 counts, C3 11 counts. In total I should be getting 46 but its showing up as only 19.

Comment: @StevenFroast, I was thinking in Excel, I corrected it to the Google Sheets formulae :)